# Is it actually possible to make very smooth hazelnut spread without industrial machines? If so, how?

Tags: nuts

I just bought this amazing spread.

**NOTE:** *Please somebody with good judgement reopen this question.* The spread I described includes NON-soaked, but roasted, nuts. The answer linked talks about grinding soaked nuts, which is a totally different scenario. Also, that answer doesn't have clear, good answers -- some of them advise they can use a blender, some others mention the grinder. THIS is a GOOD question, with an AWESOME, precise answer. I hope somebody with good judgement understands that there is a LOT of merit in this question. I made an AMAZING spread following the advice here -- advice that members of the community are going to miss out on.

Please note: I have not trying to achieve "nut butter" using **soaked** nuts. I am trying to make a **spread** using **dry** nuts. So, [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/104272/what-is-the-best-type-of-machine-for-making-smooth-nut-butter) (where the OP is trying to improve texture from *soaked* nuts) is NOT related to my question. I had found that question before/answer in my initial request, and discarded it as it is **not** relevant.

The ingredients are so simple, it's ridiculous:

- Roasted hazelnutz (46%)
- Raw and coconut sugar
- Coconut milk powder
- Sunflower oil
- Cacao butter
- Sunflower Lecithin
- Salt

I tried so many times to replicate it... and I've never come close.

**The biggest problem is the consistency**. This product is smooth. Like really, really, really smooth. If you try and chew it, there is no texture, it's just a smooth adorable soft paste.

The second problem is the taste, that isn't quite right -- and this seems to be related to the consistency issue above

**What I tried**
In pretty much every attempt, I tried making the roasted hazelnut butter first. I used (tortured) my Thermomix to crunch the hazelnuts into a butter. I never manage to get them creamy without some sunflower oil. I tend to spin it really fast (maybe that's a mistake) and for a long time (that might also be a mistake, affecting the taste). I assume the more it spins, the smoother it gets (although I am doubting it).

So, the question:

**What is the secret to this thing's smoothness**?

Do they have industrial machines that magically make this creamy? If so, is any attempt to replicate this miraculous smoothness futile?

I just wasted $50 in roasted hazelnuts for my last attempt. I am ready to give up.

Comment: Please reopen. It's not related to the [this answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/104272/what-is-the-best-type-of-machine-for-making-smooth-nut-butter); this one has valuable information, and it corrects a lot of rubbish out there.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be a duplicate. First, there is no evidence that the spread you describe uses soaked or unsoaked nuts; you don't know what the manufacturer's process is like, and this wouldn't appear on an ingredients list. Second, the tools used for crushing nuts into paste are the same, no matter if soaked or not. Soaking can help if you are struggling because you're using the wrong tool, but your question is the opposite, for finding the right tool, and that's exactly what the other question asks about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don’t need industrial equipment, but you do need something designed to grind things into a smooth paste, which a “thermomix” is not. You will not be able to do this with any sort of blade-based thing. As the particles get smaller, the blade loses its ability to further break them down.

The normal appliance one would use is a “wet grinder”.

Comment: I have a slow juicer with an oscar front end. Would that possibly be a something that will grind them to a total paste?

Comment: Does "wet grinder" mean that it will add water to my mix?

Comment: No, to both of your questions.

Comment: Damn, I would have loved to be able to make something like this without buying equipment... and cool. Thank you very much.

Comment: Would this be worthwhile buying for $50? (second hand) https://imgur.com/a/QT3MTPw Is this what home wet grinders look like? (They seem to be VERY popular in India!)

Answer (score 1):

As per [Sneftel's answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/124060/36356), you won't get far with your food processor. In terms of equipment you may already have, or at least can obtain more readily than a wet grinder, a **pestle and mortar** would be my recommendation. It should get you much further than your Thermomix, although it may take a long time and you probably won't be able to get the completely smooth texture of the industrial product.

Comment: Would this be worthwhile buying for $50? (second hand) imgur.com/a/QT3MTPw Is this what home wet grinders look like? (They seem to be VERY popular in India!)